Downloading dataset from ONA using R
is there a function to download datasets from ONA using form id and token with R
I tried this code below to download a dataset from a form id but it didn't work
dataobject <- onaDownload("form_id_string","account","username","password")


does the onaDownload function exist?

this question will likely be closed if you do not provide more details about your specific goals, the coded you tried, the data you are using and the expected output. Showing little effort will also increase the chances of getting a question closed.

If you mean Ona.R there's a step-by-step guide here https://onaio.github.io/ona.R/demo/Basics_of_ona.R.html . Also, what does didn't work  mean, what's the error message you receive? If problems persist please update you question through edit with package info, code example and expected output.
